# Calculate average number of probes with Separate chaining

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

Suppose we are given the hash table below: 
[image]

where the collision resolution method is Separate chaining. I am trying to calculate the average number of probes to find an empty slot. According to my lecture slides the average is 1.77, but I keep getting a different answer. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I solved this task using 2 methods and got 1.625 value as a result. Maybe you missunderstood something.

Comment: The question could be usefully reworded, as 1) it's initially unclear whether you're interested in collisions when inserting further elements, or reviewing the collisions that occurred when the existing elements were inserted, and 2) it's more normal to use the terms *slots* and *probes* to describe the hash table buckets and comparisons therewith, not link list traversal and comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it works like this: The idea is if you hit an empty bucket, then you are done. But if you hit a non-empty bucket, you need to traverse the chain and find a empty slot at the end of the chain.

So the resulting average probe hits is:

```
(8 empty slots * (1 probe/empty slot)) / 13 total slots
+
(2 slots with one element *(2 probes for slot with one element) /13 total slots
+
(2 slots with two elements *(3 probes for slot with two elements) /13 total slots
+
(1 slots with four elements *(5 probes for slot with four elements) /13 total slots

= 8/13 + 4/13 + 6/13 + 5/13

= 23/13

= 1.77
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to find out average probes for empty slot in Separate Chaining method. It would be of concern in Open Addressing method. And it would depend on nature of your data i.e. what is probability of getting hash-code%12 among already occupied index locations.

If you are just interested in metrics for given array:

> There are 10 elements in array of size 13. So:
>
> Minimum probability of finding empty location is 3/13 - when each 10
>   elements lands in different bucket
>
> Maximum probability of finding empty location is 12/13 (if all 10
>   elements land in one bucket)
>
> For given data it is 8/13